# Bigquery linear regression outputs different pvalues and std errors training the same model multiple times and data

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, linear-regression

I am training a linear regression model and then checking the coefficients, p-values, and standard errors by training the same model and data for multiple times. This is the code I am using:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `music_min_model`

  OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE = 'LINEAR_REG',
      INPUT_LABEL_COLS = ['music_mins_7d_post'],
      OPTIMIZE_STRATEGY = 'NORMAL_EQUATION',
      ENABLE_GLOBAL_EXPLAIN = TRUE,
      CALCULATE_P_VALUES = TRUE,
      CATEGORY_ENCODING_METHOD='DUMMY_ENCODING',
      DATA_SPLIT_METHOD = 'NO_SPLIT'
      ) AS
  

  SELECT experiment_group_name,
  experiment_id,
  IF (wau_pre = 1, music_mins_7d, 0) AS music_mins_7d_pre,
  IF (wau_post= 1, music_mins_7d,0) AS music_mins_7d_post
  FROM `wau_podcast_music_metrics`; 
  
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `music_min_estimates` AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM `music_min_estimates` -- TABLE WITH ESTIMATES FROM SINGLE CH EXPERIMENTS
  
  UNION ALL 
  
  SELECT * FROM
    ( WITH estimates_raw AS (
        SELECT 000 AS experiment_id,
              category,
              weight,
              standard_error, 
              p_value
        FROM ML.ADVANCED_WEIGHTS(MODEL `music_min_model`) 
        WHERE category IS NOT NULL and NOT (IS_NAN (p_value))
        )

      SELECT 0 as model_nmr,
      experiment_id,
      IF (category = 'groupA', weight * -1, weight) AS estimate,
      standard_error, 
      p_value
      FROM estimates_raw
      ) -- TABLE WITH POOLED VERSION
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Am I missing some parameter in the options clause?

Comment: I would suggest filing a support case for this inquiry, as I believe it will require some sensitive project information(might be dangerous if posted to public) to investigate error further, Please visit this documentation for reference on how to file a support case: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/customer-care-procedures#create_a_support_case

Comment: I am in contact with a support engineer from google. Apparently they have a bug in their systems. They re rolling out a new version at the beginning of the year. 'll keep posted